# Remove getParameters from the url

Tags: apex, parameters

`ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters()`

by having the above line its generating parameters:

`DEBUG|pageref  : System.PageReference[/500/e?ekp=500&ent=Case&isdtp=Ww&isWsVw=true&save_new=1&sfdc.override=1`

My question, i'm trying to remove the following parameters `ekp` & `save_new` How would I do that?

```
public PageReference redirectPage() 
{
  PageReference page = new PageReference('/' +   Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/e');
  Map<String, String> param = p.getParameters();
  param.putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());     
  return page;    
}
```

Comment: If you want to remove it from the param Map than please read the Map documentation. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm%23apex_System_Map_methods. Look for the remove method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see params is Map of strings so you can remove any key from map

```
public PageReference redirectPage() 
{
    PageReference currentPage = ApexPages.currentPage();
    Map<String, String> params  =  currentPage.getParameters(); 
    //remove ekp and save_new key
    params.remove('ekp');
    params.remove('save_new');
    currentPage.getParameters().putAll(params);
    currentPage  =  new PageReference(currentPage.getURL());
    currentPage.setRedirect(true);
    return currentPage;    

}
```

Comment: didn't even read the question, but google knew what I'm after... this answer worked perfectly for me, thank you so much.